# Why relative paths in python don't work when run from C#, but do work when using the same interpreter outside of c#?

Tags: c#, python, asp.net-core

I'm trying to run a python script from C# that reads a file in the same directory as the python script.

```py
with open('./input.txt') as f:
    print(f.read().strip())
```

Here is the minimal working example of the c# code:

```cs
var pi = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = @"path-to-python.exe",
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    RedirectStandardError = true,
    Arguments = @"path-to-script.py",
};

using (var p = Process.Start(pi))
using (var reader = p.StandardOutput)
{
    var err = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
    var res = reader.ReadToEnd();
    Console.WriteLine(err);
    Console.WriteLine(res);
}
```

So far, I've tried:

1. running the python script from cmd with the same interpreter I provide to c#, the "path-to-python.exe", that works.
2. specifying the full absolute path in the python script and running it from c#, that works too.

The error message I keep getting is:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: './input.txt'
```

Comment: try using ```os.path.join()``` instead of writing paths using strings like this: ```"./folder/something_else/input.txt"```

Comment: Yeah, I tried that, that works as well, the problem is that I generally have a bunch of python files that I don't want to change at all. So the solution for me is to copy them inside the debug folder for development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
print(os.getcwd())
```

answers this question really

```
Project\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.2
```

Obviously c# runs the python file not from it's current location but rather from the debug, should have been obvious.